# list comprehension logic behind when add Zip function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python code below

```
    x = [1, 2,1]
    y = [0]
    lis=[l+r for l,r in zip(x+y,y+x)]
    lis
```

The output is [1,3,3,1]
Not sure how this works

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for Python's [built-in zip() function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down.

```
x+y
```

and

```
y+x
```

`x+y` creates a new list with the elements `[1, 2, 1, 0]`, and `y+x` will create `[0, 1, 2, 1]`.

```
zip(x+y,y+x)
```

`zip` will then merge the 2 lists into a list of tuples: `[(1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2), 0, 1)]`

```
[l+r for l,r in zip(x+y,y+x)]
```

Now that we know what `zip(x+y,y+x)` generates, it is simply a list function that will add the 2 values in the tuples (the `l+r` part) into a number again and store it back into a list: `[1+0, 2+1, 1+2, 0+1] = [1, 3, 3, 1]`

Comment: `x+y and y+x` should be separated to "`x+y` and `y+x`", otherwise it looks like a line of (perfectly valid) python code, which probably doesn't do what you'd think at first glance.

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought about that, have changed it now.

Comment: They should be on the same line though... If you remove the indent, and write it as ``​`x+y` and `y+x`​`` it'll treat them as in-line code so you can have both on the same line.